# youtube api v3 insert playlistitem fails with automatically date sorted playlist

Tags: youtube-api

I am having problems with inserting to a automatically sorted playlist. 
I get a response: status(400,Bad Request)

After I change at Youtube to Playlists->Playlist settings->Ordering->Manual, my insertion works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was sending a "playlist position"-parameter with the request. That's why it did fail.